# How Do you combine CSS code to an HTML code? I want to Combine them?

Tags: html, css

Can you please copy and paste your answer with the final code? This is an image mapping code for an image with HMTL, I now want to add a CSS shadow to it.

*Here is the code:*

```
<style>
{
-moz-box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #888;
box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #888;
}

</style>
```

*And Below is the HTML code that I need to add the CSS shadow code to the image in it:*

```
<div style="text-align:center; width:1130px; auto; auto;">
<img id="Image-Maps_9201304191940558" src="http://images.mylot.com/userImages/images/postphotos/2080106.jpg" usemap="#Image-Maps_9201304191940558" border="0" width="1130" height="2808" alt="" />

<map id="_Image-Maps_9201304191940558" name="Image-Maps_9201304191940558">
<area shape="rect" coords="293,566,385,603" href="http://www..com/about" alt="about" title="about" />
<area shape="rect" coords="631,568,720,603" href="http://www..com/contact" alt="contact" title="contact" />

</map>

</div>
```

So I just want to combine the codes together! I originally asked this on yahoo answers so now Im asking it here cause no one could help there.

Thanks

Comment: You need to read up about the fundamental bits of CSS - Google a tutorial - there are plenty of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'correct' method is to put the css in one file and the html in another, then link the css file from the `<head>` section of the html file (for many reasons, we try to maintain best practices, but the main reason is code maintainability and reusability -- by splitting these files, you keep the code more readable and maintainable for yourself, and you allow yourself to re-use the css file in multiple HTML files).

For example:

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles.css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='stylediv'>
        <img id="Image-Maps_9201304191940558" src="http://images.mylot.com/userImages/images/postphotos/2080106.jpg" usemap="#Image-Maps_9201304191940558" border="0" width="1130" height="2808" alt="" />

        <map id="_Image-Maps_9201304191940558" name="Image-Maps_9201304191940558">
            <area shape="rect" coords="293,566,385,603" href="http://www.google.com/about" alt="about" title="about" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="631,568,720,603" href="http://www.google.com/contact" alt="contact" title="contact" />
        </map>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

styles.css:

```css
#stylediv {
    text-align:center; 
    width:1130px; 
    margin: auto;
    -moz-box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #888;
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #888;
}
```

It is permissible to put the styles in-line. You could even put them in the `style=` attribute of the `<div>` tag but the above is best practice.

Note that `id` is unique, so if you want to apply the above css to multiple divs, you would instead use `class=stylediv` and change `#stylediv` in the css to `.stylediv`.

Comment: It did not work for me, not sure why. so what would the final code product look like inline? All in one together without linking to seperate files?

Comment: Replace `<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='styles.css'>` with `<style type='text/css'>`, then put the contents of `styles.css` after that tag, then close with `</style>`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using any selector for your CSS declaration

```
div {
    -moz-box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #888;
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #888; 
}
```

If you need to target img tag you can use `div img {}` selector, it is better to use a class instead of using element selectors

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/L76AR/)

Note - The shadow is to the bottom so you need to scroll down.

Comment: I have no idea what any of that means, can you please paste the final product code? What it would look like?  Can you give it the name or whatever that it needs?

Comment: @mike You wanted a shadow around your image, I've provided you a demo for that

Comment: No sorry, I dont know coding at all, it doesnt make any sense to me, I was hoping for a final code I can just copy and paste. My entire site is just an image mapping html code, there is nothing else to it, just a big image with an html image mapping code.

Comment: @mike You need a mapping thing or do you need shadows? If you are not comfortable with mapping, simply wrap your image in a `position: relative;` container and use `a` anchors with position absolute and simple set them using top,left, right bottom on your image

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <img id="Image-Maps_9201304191940558" src="http://images.mylot.com/userImages/images/postphotos/2080106.jpg" usemap="#Image-Maps_9201304191940558" border="0" width="1130" height="2808" alt="" />
  <map id="_Image-Maps_9201304191940558" name="Image-Maps_9201304191940558">
    <area shape="rect" coords="293,566,385,603" href="http://www.google.com/about" alt="about" title="about" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="631,568,720,603" href="http://www.google.com/contact" alt="contact" title="contact" />
  </map>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  text-align: center;
  width: 1130px;
}

img {
  -moz-box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #888;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #888;
  box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #888;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what any of that means, can you please paste the final product code? What it would look like?  Can you give it the name or whatever that it needs?  Thanks....

Comment: I can't really give you the final product code because you didn't give us any idea about what the rest of the code looks like. But those two snippets of code that I provided will do the image box-shadow effect. Place the HTML part above where you want it to appear inside the `<body>`, and the CSS part together with the other CSS styles that you have.

Answer (score 1):

You need to name the css with the name of the div

```
<style>
#divName{
-moz-box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #888;
box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px #888;
}
<style>
```

Then your html div will need to have matching divName

id uses # while class uses a .

```
<div id="divName"> Pic with Shadow </div>
```

Need to use the selector in the CSS which is the #divName